# What is this green dot near the light in this photo and what's causing it?

Tags: troubleshooting, ghosting

Here is the photo:
[image]

Is there a name for this effect and is there any way to prevent this from happening? This photo was taken on a Nikon D60 with a Nikkor 50mm 1.8G lens.

The setting were f/1.8 1/40 ISO-400

This is not the same as the question `is it normal to get significant lens flare with a 50mm f/1.8 Canon prime lens?` as this question is mainly based on what this effect is called, not whether it is normal or not.

Comment: In your case the ghosting appears to be caused by a flat rear surface near the front of your lens, probably an UV or other "protective" filter.

Comment: Voting to reopen because this is not correct choice of duplicated question.

Comment: This is called "lens flare" and as you may notice upon closer inspection it is centrally symmetrical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are reflections of the lights. The most common cause of this is using a filter in front of the lens since its flat surface makes reflection easier to occur and in a more predictable pattern. The other reason is internal reflection inside the lens. There is nothing to do about it except buy a lens which is more resistant to flare. Modern lens have nano-crystal coating which reduce the problem although it cannot always be eliminated in all cases.

Comment: I do have a cheap UV filter on the front so that's probably it. Thank you!

Comment: If you're going to put a piece of glass in front of your lens, I'd think you'd want it to be, at least, of equal quality to the lens itself.

Answer (score 1):

That's the light reflecting off your sensor (and reflecting off the lens elements and back onto the sensor) which happens to be extremely reflective. A filter at the end of your lens makes this problem worse, but it is there, nevertheless, without such filters. Try stopping down the lens, and shooting such lights more off center.